# How to run docker rmi $(docker images -a -q) in Jenkins as part of ssh script

Tags: linux, bash, docker, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am building a Jenkins jobs to build docker container on AWS EC2 instance and this is a sample of a Jenkins script that is giving errors:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
# Not giving the IP here but I guess you can understand
HOST = Some IP address of EC2 instance in AWS 

# Current Project workspace 
# Download source code and create a tar and then SCP it in to AWS EC2
# So my Code is copied in to AWS EC2 instance now ...
# Now do the SSH and run the script on AWS EC2 instance
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i MySecrets.pem ec2-user@$HOST \
    "tar xvf pc.tar && \
    cd my_project_source_code && \
    docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) && \
    docker rmi $(docker images -a -q) && \
    sh -c 'nohup docker-compose kill  > /dev/null 2>&1 &' && \
    docker-compose build --no-cache && \
    sh -c 'nohup docker-compose up > /dev/null 2>&1 &' "
```

When I build this job in Jenkins, it fails with following error on output console :

> "docker stop" requires at least 1 argument(s). See 'docker stop
>   --help'.
>
> Usage:  docker stop [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
>
> Stop one or more running containers Build step 'Execute shell' marked
>   build as failure

**So my question is what is wrong with my bash script here ?**

On a separate note :

I am able to run the  **docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)** when I ssh into the EC2 on a CLI. But when same commands run in the Jenkins jobs bash shell script it does not recognize this as valid script. What am I doing wrong here ? This appears to be some misunderstanding from my side on how to run this command in Jenkins Job's bash shell script, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: Putting it in double quotes makes the command substitution run locally, not on the remote end.

Comment: BTW -- why the `sh -c`? All this is being run in a shell already; why invoke another one?

Comment: Also, making assumptions about ordering between a background process and the steps that follow it in your script is generally speaking a bad idea. You have no reasonable basis on which to believe that `docker-compose kill` will reliably and consistently take effect before `docker-compose build` does here, particularly when you're looping extra commands like `sh` and `nohup` into the startup process for the former.

Comment: As another aside, using all-caps `HOST` as a variable name is a bad idea. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the shell and OS, while names with lowercase characters are reserved for application use.

Comment: Regarding why sh -C? I want to spawn a new shell with background process using nohup so when this current shell terminates my other shell with background process continues without interruption.

Comment: Why do you think you need `sh -c` to do that? The shell that's directly invoked by `ssh` is perfectly capable of invoking `nohup` itself (or, better, directly spawning a child process and disowning it without the need of a silly tool that does nothing but duplicate built-in shell functionality).

Comment: ...that is to say: `docker-compose kill >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null & disown -h "$!"` does everything nohup does, without the external dependency and without the silly `nohup.out` default.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Cool !! Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want substitutions within your script to run on the remote side, it needs to be passed to `ssh` in a context where the local shell won't try to evaluate it first. Double quotes aren't that context.

A quoted heredoc will fit the bill:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i MySecrets.pem "ec2-user@$HOST" 'bash -s' <<'EOF'
 tar xvf pc.tar                                        || exit
 cd my_project_source_code                             || exit
 docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)                        || exit
 docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)                     || exit
 sh -c 'nohup docker-compose kill  > /dev/null 2>&1 &' || exit
 docker-compose build --no-cache                       || exit
 sh -c 'nohup docker-compose up > /dev/null 2>&1 &'    || exit
EOF
```